# Python regular expression for matching '0' with no decimal point

Tags: python, regex

Consider the multiline string

```
text = """SPLINE
        8                                     # <------ everything from here
0
       70
    12
       71
     2
       72
     8
       73
     5
       42
   0.1000000000000000E-08
       43
   0.1000000000000000E+01
       40
   0.1000000000000000E+01
       40
   0.1157776718684309E+01
       41
   0.9237223003012139E+00
       20
  -0.3529600706727810E+02                     # <--------- to here
  0
LINE
        8
0
       10
   0.1069999999749793E+02
       20
  -0.3165748401599828E+02
       30
   0.0000000000000000E+00
  0
ARC"""
```

What regular expression can I use to obtain everything between `SPLINE` and the `0` just above `LINE`?

I've tried

```
re.findall(r'SPLINE(.*?)\s\s[0]', text, re.DOTALL)
```

and many variations thereof which get me close, but are ultimately not what I need. The issue I suppose is just with the end part of the regex (the `\s\s[0]` part) given that `SPLINE` is matched no problem.

Another way of posing my question would be to ask what regex I could use to match two spaces followed by the integer 0 without a decimal point.

Comment: Have you tried `SPLINE(.*?)\r\n0`?  What about `SPLINE(.*?)\n0` ?

Comment: `SPLINE(.*?)\r\n0` returns an empty list and `SPLINE(.*?)\n0` returns `['\n        8']`

Comment: Could there be whitespace at work here as well?  Your regex looks right to me except possibly for this.

Comment: My regex is ended by `\s\s\s0.1000000000000000E-08` so it seems to be detecting the whitespace fine, but not detecting that `0.100...E-08` isn't an integer.

Comment: It is not numeric if it has the letter `E` in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly trivial, just needed to add a newline character to skip over all the decimals. Successful regex was `SPLINE(.*?)\s\s0\n`, such that

```
re.findall('SPLINE(.*?)\s\s0\n', text, re.DOTALL)
```

did the trick.